# Can I use the Application class as the Model for MVC in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Sorry. I'm new, so I'm experienced, but to follow the MVC design pattern in Android, where is the model stored? I was thinking in Application since it pretty much has a very wide scope and any component can pull from it. Is this a good way of thinking?

Comment: The title of your question is misleading, but upon reading, your understanding of MVC is less weird than it seemed :). I'd say, "yes", the Application is a reasonable anchor point for the global transient state of your app. It's readily accessible and effectively singleton. That said, most people seem to just use a classic `static Blah instance` signleton object for their global transient state.

Comment: One thing to be aware of: if your app is in the background, the OS can decide to kill its Linux process to free up memory. When your app is later resumed, it'll be running in a fresh process, and all the static variables are reset. Make sure you use the Activities' lifecycle methods to persist everything you need to persist (`onPause()`/`onSaveInstanceState()`).

Answer (score 0):

On a project that we have here, we do use the Application to persist it but in a certain structured pattern.

Just to start with, the Model is, as you would guess, layered through classes that will represent your persistent entities, so e.g. if you persist clients, you will have a Client class that will hold it's structure, so I guess when you say about Model, I think you talk about the persistence of state-full model objects that will live across your application lifecycle.

We use android annotations just to start with. We use singleton classes (Annotated with @EBean(scope=Scope.singleton)) and our Application object has a reference to that singleton. 
We have other entities (singletons as well) that we use as controllers that are the only ones that are able to access and manipulate at certain degrees with that "model singleton" and our activities have an interface-like communication with the controllers, those controllers can access the persistent data on the "model singleton" and provide feedback to the activities through it's interface.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's probably better to use a `ContentProvider` or even a singleton class.  The problem with keeping state in your `Application` is that if any part of your app ever needs to run in a different process, that process will have its own copy of the `Application`.  Running things in separate processes isn't common, but there are a few reasons to do it.  A singleton class doesn't address the problem of sharing state with another process, but the other process might not care about the application's model.  If the model is in the `Application`, the other process gets a copy whether it wants it or not.